# Add Groovy dynamic method to Spring controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, groovy

Have a Groovy Spring app, and i'm trying to add a method to a controller class on app start. Like:

```
@Configuration
class AppConfig implements InitializingBean {
    void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
       MyCtrl ctrl = applicationContext.getBean(...)
       ctrl.metaClass.render = { String x ->
           ...
       }
    }
}
```

for a Groovy class like:

```
@Controller
class MyCtrl {

   ModelAndView show() {     
     ...
     println this.metaClass.methods*.name
     println MyCtrl.metaClass.methods*.name
     println this
     println this.class == MyCtrl
     render('show')
   }

}
```

And getting exception:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.company.MyCtrl.render() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [/index]
Possible solutions: render(java.lang.String), index(), find(), every(), every(groovy.lang.Closure), find(groovy.lang.Closure)
```

Notice that Groovy mention this method in "Possible solutions" list.

In console I see following:

```
[equals, getClass, hashCode, notify, notifyAll, toString, wait, wait, wait, __$swapInit, getMetaClass, getProperty, index, invokeMethod, setMetaClass, setProperty]

[render, equals, getClass, hashCode, notify, notifyAll, toString, wait, wait, wait, __$swapInit, getMetaClass, getProperty, index, invokeMethod, setMetaClass, setProperty]

com.company.MyCtrl@3e52f8c1

true
```

As I see, `this.metaClass` doesn't see my dynamic method `render`, but `MyCtrl.metaClass` sees it. And sure, it's same class, `MyCtrl == this.getClass()`

What's the difference? What i've missed there? Tried to use `ExpandoMetaClass` and/or apply class instead of instance, same result. Doesn't work.

It's not the first time i'm adding methods through metaClass, and was always working fine. Just the first time adding to a Spring Controller. Maybe it conflicts with Spring reflections, used for controller? Not sure how to check

PS Groovy 2.3, Java 7, Spring 4.0.3

Comment: What's the exact type of `this`? Add `println this.getClass();`.

Comment: `this` is `com.company.MyCtrl@3e52f8c1`

Comment: The behavior would make more sense if it was a Proxy class :-/ As I see it, `this.metaClass` must be different from `MyCtrl.metaClass` but my understanding is that Groovy keeps a cache of all meta classes and looks that up every time you access it. So the question boils down to "What does Groovy really do when you write `this.metaClass`?"

Comment: Can you also try `MyCtrl.metaClass.render = ...` (i.e. without going via the bean)?

Comment: Yes, tried also. Nothing changed

Comment: Try to debug the code which gets executed when the script executes `this.metaClass`. There must be a difference to the lookup via the type.

Answer (score 0):

You have this...

```
MyCtrl ctrl = applicationContext.getBean(...)
ctrl.metaClass.render = { String x ->
    ...
}
```

That is not modifying the `MyCtrl` metaclass.  That is modifying the metaclass for that particular instance of `MyCtrl`.  Depdending on some other factors in your app which are not present in your description, that may not be what you want.  You probably want to modify the `MyCtrl` metaclass with something like this...

```
MyCtrl.metaClass.render = { String x ->
    ...
}
```